# Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service _after_ implementing AdMob

Tags: swift, xcode, admob

I just integrated AdMob into my project and I get a whole bunch of these error messages in the Xcode output.

The app does not communicate w/ the internet and does not open up WKView (all I found n SO was references to WKWebView like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44623268/14414215 but doesn't seem to be related to me since I don't use WKWebView). All I did was integrate Google-Mobile-Ads using cocoa pods and followed the Admob support pages.

Some SO Pages talk about ATS, but google support pages don't have the same error message (https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/app-transport-security)

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource
> load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via
> your app's Info.plist file.

Its happening both on simulator and real device. Is this a real issue or something I can ignore?

Also, there's a ton of messages coming out from the Admob SDK, it's frankly a bit annoying to filter through.

Answer (score 0):

The Messages in the console remains and does not seem to affect the app performance (AFAICT) and while it is excessive, I have silenced them some-what using environment variable ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/64471106/14414215) in my scheme. (per below pictures)

[image]
[image]

Take note however, if you do have issues w/ Google-Mobile-Ads, please be reminded to remove this such that you will be able to see the console messages.